# Android volley request to get tokens 400 error

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, android-volley

I'm trying to call an ASP.net web api getTokens POST method on my server from Android using Volley.

I'm getting a 400 error from the server which i believe is a bad request.

I've tried a couple of different things E.g. setting the content-type to both

```
headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

.
and

```
headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

but it does not make a difference which i use. i believe it should be set to application/json when using Android.

I've seen other posts on SO that have mentioned the getHeaders Override does not set the header in some cases.

Can anyone see what the problem is?

```
try {




                JSONObject js = new JSONObject();
                try {

                    js.put("client_id", "HKTPEMS");
                    js.put("client_secret", "B83845-9AFDDD-46D7B487D");
                    js.put("grant_type", "password");
                    js.put("username", firstName);
                    js.put("password", password);

                }catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }






                JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(
                        Request.Method.POST, url, js, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "response = " + response.toString());

                                iResult.notifySuccess(response);


                                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                                String accessToken = null;
                                String refreshToken = null;

                                try {


                                    //Get the accessToken
                                    accessToken = (String) response.get("access_token");
                                    Log.e(TAG, "accessToken = " + accessToken);

                                    //Get the refreshToken
                                    refreshToken = (String) response.get("refresh_token");
                                    Log.e(TAG, "refreshToken = " + refreshToken);

                                }catch (Exception e){}




                                cv.putNull(LoginValidate.C_ID_TOKENS);
                                cv.put(LoginValidate.C_TOKENS_ACCESS_TOKEN, accessToken);
                                cv.put(LoginValidate.C_TOKENS_REFRESH_TOKEN, refreshToken);

                                appObj.loginValidate.insertIntoTokens(cv);




                                cvResult.put("resultcode", "OK");




                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error stackTrace: " + error.getStackTrace().toString());

                        iResult.notifyError(error);

                    }
                }) {


                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                        //headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                        return headers;
                    }



                };


                RequestQueue queue = appObj.getRequestQueue();
                queue.add(jsonObjReq);






            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("json","e.getLocalizedMessage()"+ e.getLocalizedMessage());
                cvResult.put("resultcode", "ERROR: problem getting the tokens");
            }
```

.

```
/WebServicesForWebApi: inside WS getAuthenticationTokens()
 E/LoginValidate: url already exists in DB, so returning it
 E/WebServicesForWebApi: checking url for getting tokens. url = https://abc.xyz.co.uk/Token
 E/LoginValidate: password already exists in DB, so returning it
 E/LoginValidate: username already exists in DB, so returning it
 E/WebServicesForWebApi: username = de4bcbc0bac3@XXXX.com
 E/WebServicesForWebApi: password = 90661f6a-11c0-4bb3-b92a-cd9e38dfd229
 E/WebServicesForWebApi: tokenCountInDB = 0
 E/InstallationActivity: ContententsValues for tokens has size = 0
 I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
 I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
 E/Volley: [55345] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://abc.xyz.co.uk/Token
 E/WebServicesForWebApi: Error: null
 E/WebServicesForWebApi: Error stackTrace: [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@33976bc
 E/InstallationActivity: ERROR for getAuthenticationTokens() = com.android.volley.ServerError
```

[EDIT1]

```
JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
                jsonBody.put("scope", "openid email phone profile offline_access roles");
                jsonBody.put("resource", "window.location.origin");
                jsonBody.put("grant_type", "password");
                jsonBody.put("username", "support@care.com");
                jsonBody.put("password", "tempP@ss");
                final String requestBody = jsonBody.toString();
```

Comment: There is no specific `Content-Type` that works for all. It really depends on the server implementation. I think you should leave this code and try to connect to the server first using your computer using any HTTP client like Postman and after you know how the request should look like, you should then and only then try to implement it on your app.

Comment: @AhmedHegazy Hi, my colleague who has written the server side code has already done this using Postman and can confirm it works. It seems to be a problem with an Android client

Comment: I would ask him to export the full working request and compare it to yours using wireshark or some proxy which records requests

Comment: @AhmedHegazy i downloaded an app called Django Rest Client so i could inspect the response. It said invalid clientid. Ihave pointed my android project at another token project from a different developer, which uses different params and different token code. i still get a 400 with too. this is what i sent in EDIT1